# Conversion fail from MSSQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I encountered a problem when trying to convert MSSQL code to MySQL.

#### My MSSQL code is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProductGroupGenerationSettingsCheck  
AS  
declare @id bit , @result varchar(50);  

SELECT  @id = automaticProductIdGeneration   
FROM         tbl_Settings--)  

if(@id =0)  
 begin  
 set @result='false'  
 end  

else if (@id =1)  
 begin  
 set @result='true'  
 end  


select @result
```

#### My MySQL code is:

```
delimiter //
create procedure ProductGroupGenerationSettingsCheck(p_id tinyint(1),p_result varchar(50))
begin
    select p_id = automaticProductIdGeneration from tbl_Settings ;
    if(p_id = 0)
    begin 
    set p_result = 'false' ;
    end
    else if (p_id = 1)
    begin
        set p_result = 'true' ;
    end

    select p_result  as 'result' ;


end //
delimiter ;
```

### the error I get is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin set p_result = 'false' ; end else if (p_id = 1) begin set p_re' at line 5

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: I dont know MySQL, but i thought in mysql you cant create stored procedures, atleast not like that

Comment: MySQL has Stored Routines: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html

Comment: i have created many time in the same procedure..

Comment: interesting  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: ha same link as Shivan!

Comment: there is some syntax error.. which i am unable to figure out...

Comment: post the complete error message. The exact position of the syntax error is mentioned in it

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin set p_result = 'false' ; end else if (p_id = 1) begin set p_re' at line 5

Comment: Thanks @Jess Stone for editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delimiter //
create procedure ProductGroupGenerationSettingsCheck(IN p_id tinyint(1),IN p_result varchar(50)) /*specify what type of parameter it is, IN / OUT / INOUT*/
begin
    select p_id := automaticProductIdGeneration from tbl_Settings ; /*use assignment operator := instead of comparison =*/
    if(p_id = 0) then /*missing a then here*/
    begin 
    set p_result = 'false' ;
    /*don't end the if, when you still have an else if condition*/
    else if (p_id = 1) then /*missing a then again*/
    begin
        set p_result = 'true' ;
    end
    end if; /*missing an if here*/

    select p_result  as 'result' ; /*you could also use an OUT parameter for this...anyway...*/


end //
delimiter ;
```

- [manual entry if statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/if.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are one error in the query at the forth line. Yo must use the next query.

```
select automaticProductIdGeneration into p_id from tbl_Settings;
```

It could be usefull if you post the entire error message. It shows you where is exactly the first problem.